# How to pass an array when navigating via routing

Tags: sapui5

I have the next trouble, I'm trying to pass an array of data to other view for populate a table in SAPUI5, but I don't get it, I'm trying this:

Worklist controller:

```js
NavAsignTecnico: function() {
  var table = this.byId("lista_ord_1");
  var itemsSelected = table.getSelectedItems();
  var array = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < itemsSelected.length; i++) {
    var item = itemsSelected[i];
    var context = item.getBindingContext();
    var value = context.getProperty("ProductId");
    array.push(value);
  }
  this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
    data: JSON.stringify(array)
  });
}
```

Prograord Controller:

```js
onInit: function() {
  var oModel, oView;
  oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTG_TEST_SRV/", true);
  oModel.setCountSupported(false);
  oView = this.getView();
  oView.setModel(oModel);
  this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this.handlerFunction, this);
},

handlerFunction: function(oEvent) {
  var some = new Array();
  var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters("arguments");
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTG_TEST_SRV/", true);
  console.log(oParameters);
  var result = [];
  var oFilters = [];
  for (var i in oParameters)
    result.push([i, oParameters[i]]);
  console.log(result);
  var list = this.getView().byId("table_ord_asign");
  var binding = list.getBinding("items");
  if (!oFilters) {
    binding.filter([]);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < oParameters.length; i++) {
      oFilters.push(new Filter("ProductId", "EQ", oParameters[i], false, true));
    }
    var json;
    console.log(oFilters);
  }
},
```

And in my compontent.js, I have this config:

```json
{
  "pattern": "Prograord/{data}",
  "name": "object",
  "target": ["object"]
}
```

Someone has any idea how to pass this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try retrieve array like this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(oEvent.getParameter("arguments").data);
```